# Android Studio signs apk different than jarsigner

Tags: android, android-studio, jarsigner

In Android Studio when I go to `Build > Generate Signed APK` the SHA1 of the apk signature generated is different than the one generated manually by `jarsigner`. Therefore, Google Play rejects the update and I must manually sign it every time. The first release of the app was signed using Eclipse with the ADT plugin, if that matters. Why does this happen?

Comment: Would the down-voter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

Because you got different key selected in Android Studio for signing this particular flavor than you used for your released builds. You need to press <kbd>F4</kbd> (or select "Open Module Settings" in "app" module context menu (RMB)) and check `Signing` and `Flavors` tabs.

Alternatively, you got no signing certificate specified there and you are being asked for one during export. But still, you seem to be selecting the wrong one.

**EDIT**

As APK is ordinary ZIP archive, you can easily extract `META-INF/CERT.RSA` file and get details of used certificate

```
keytool -printcert EXTRACTED-CERT.RSA
```

or just

```
unzip -p Name-of-apk.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert
```

if using any sane shell (not windows) and then compare outputs with recent APK

**EDIT**

Please note you shall only compare certificate fingerprint. Serial number, expiration date etc is NOT unique. **If hash (fingerprint) is different, then this is different certificate**, like it or not :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am on a Mac, what would the keyboard shortcut be?  And I am positive I am using the same keystore.

Comment: I do not know, but you can open context menu on "app" module and look for "Open Module Settings"

Comment: Ok I opened up Module Settings, but I do not have any keystore selected for the signing.  Here is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/WKUzto9,b6QFXWO#0

Comment: Then it means you are being asked for the key during exporting signed APK and you are selecting incorrect key one in that step

Comment: This is where my question comes in.  I am CERTAIN I am using the correct key, that is why this issue is so bizarre to me.

Comment: You cannot use the same key otherwise you wouldn't get certificate mismatch error.

Comment: I voted up because of the excellent command.  Using the keytool -v -list -keystore mykeystore.keystore command on my keystore, the serial number and validity date is EXACTLY the same as the output of: unzip -p Name-of-apk.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert, while the checksums differ.

Comment: serial number or validity dates are not really important as these are not guaranteed to be unique. What is however unique is certificate itself, therefore you should compare hash of the certs

Comment: The hashes are different.  I will have to manually sign until I come up with some other solution.  Thank you for your insight!